# Win + Shift + S to take screen clippings -- OneNote cannot save the screen clipping in the target section

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, screen-capture, microsoft-onenote-2016

[image]

Recently when I use the shortcut `windowskey + s + shift`  to take a screen clipping they are occasionally not getting saved into the OneNote notebook I have them all set to go to.

Of the last 10 screen clippings, this has happened 3 times.

If I notice, I can press `control + V` to paste them into the notebook, but if I overlooked it and take another clipping, the previous clipping appears to be gone forever.

What could be causing this error?
When things work properly the OneNote sidebar looks like this
[image]

when things go wrong it looks like this

[image]

Any way to prevent/solve this issue?

Comment: Only one clip is stored at a time, and it is stored in the clipboard memory so it never gets stored in the file system. There may be 3rd party clipboard managers that might do what you want.

Comment: Dang, I was afraid of that, I'll edit this question to see if there is a way to fix the error... I noticed an error on the notifications after reboot.